# Count the amount of queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to optimize my site, in order to do that I want to know which action is making more queries than others. Is there anyway to know the amount of DB hits made by **one action**?

Comment: https://github.com/comboy/sql_queries_count

Comment: Dude! This is totally what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Paired with bullet from the answer below it has done wonders in about an hour. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found these gem very helpful for inspecting issues and optimizing queries

- https://github.com/noahd1/oink
- https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Comment: and Yes newrelic is also amazing.

Comment: Newrelic rules! but it's too expensive, I've used it but to my knowledge, Newrelic lacks of this feature... I look into the gems though.

Comment: Yeah is costly Im enjoying free version :D

Answer (score 4):

This gem will do exactly what you need: show the number of db queries issued per action:

https://github.com/makandra/query_diet

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the rails log to see what & how many queries are being fired for each request. But its usually pain go though the log each time to see which request are taking time.

Usually I use newrelic gem in development to see which actions are taking more time and will try to optimize the queries. Refer to http://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode for more info on newrelic in development model.

Also based on the database and rails version there are other gems ( https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet ) which tells you how queries are performed in a particular request.

Comment: As I said to @Naveed, Newrelic is a very useful tool to measure and improve your app performance... but is not quite I'm looking for, however Bullet maybe it is what I need...